# in execCommand, How can i know all the available para for the formatblock command?

Tags: javascript

I'm writting my own rich text editor in javascript

formatBlock requires a tag-name string. I mean all the tag-name strings.

Comment: This is a poorly phrased question - what do you mean by the "formatblock" command (there isn't one)?  Why don't haven't you written an actual question in the question body?  In any case, it would probably help greatly if you gave some skeleton code showing what you would want to do, and highlight the specific bit that you're stuck on.

Comment: formatBlock requires a tag-name string. I mean all the tag-name strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite not really knowing what you're after (see my comment), it seems that you want to know more about what is possible with the `execCommand` method.  As usual, the Mozilla docs have a good reference:

[Rich-Text Editing in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla)

Of course, this only lists the commands that Firefox understands.  The list of "command identifiers" that IE supports is given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049%28VS.85%29.aspx).